# Can I download .zip file to the browser using ajax?

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, browser

I'm using spring boot as my backend and I need to download .zip file to the browser which is in a remote server.
Can I do it using ajax or is there any other method to download .zip file to the browser.

Comment: If you mean to offer the user to save it, download it normally by navigating to its URL.

Comment: .$ajax ({url:url}) i tried like this but it didnt work.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=make+browser+download+file